# Problem with running code with google.colab in Pycharm

Tags: python

So I'm trying to run a code that does image processing for machine learning, and I'm using this code "from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow"

and it gives me this error

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'
```

I tried using pip install google-colab but it gives me an error code in the terminal saying

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
  Running setup.py clean for pandas
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: are you running 32-bit Python?